# See Custom Account Field in Contact List View

Tags: related-list, list-view, campaign-member, workflowrule

Thank you in advance for reading this! We would like to create a Campaign for all Contacts that are associated with Accounts that have a value selected for a custom picklist field.

Example-
We have identified a subset of Accounts that we have researched and rated as a likely prospect for a certain product line. The Custom Account Field is a picklist with values:  Target, Hot, Warm, Cold, Dead. 
I want create a Contact List view that will show me Contacts that are associated with Target Accounts.

Can you help guide me on the best way to accomplish this? 
1) Workflow: Create a field update workflow rule so that IF the person's related Company is marked as a Target it will update a custom Contact field, "XYZ Target"?  If this is a viable solution, HOW would I do that? 
2) Create a Campaign and then add members via a cross object report?

Answer (score 1):

You can run an Accounts & Contacts report to add all of the contacts to the campaign using the Add to Campaign button after running the report. This will allow you to filter by any contact or account field that can be filtered.

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula field on Contact to pull the value from account.

Use that field in you list views / criteria